# Unable to Connect to Server in Microsoft SSMS 2017

Tags: ssms

Unable to Connect to Server in Microsoft SSMS 
Getting the below error! Please refer to the attachment for more details.

[image: Error Image]

### Error Details: TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to root.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=53&LinkId=20476

---

The network path was not found

---

Comment: Is there a computer on your network named `root`? If so, does it have a default instance of SQL Server installed on it? If so, is the service running? Protocols enabled in Configuration Manager? You're missing almost everything needed for people to help you.

Comment: I was trying to connect it to my oracle mysql server.

Comment: that will never work. SSMS is a client exclusively for MS SQL Server. It will not work with Oracle, MySQL, Postgres, SQLite or any other database.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your server name regularly is localhost instead of root. Second, from SSMS 16 up, you need additional installation of localhost server. You can read the reference [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4226fc1d-f2a9-445c-ba90-4bd19321ad59/after-installing-ssms-2016-cant-connect-to-localhost?forum=sqltools).

Answer (score 0):

After numerous attempts I tried many versions, I was able to fix this issue by installing the SQL Server 17. I was successfully able to create a server and connect to SQL Server.